# Natural maps of a homotopy limit are preserved by homotopy

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I am using the definition of homotopy limits in terms of ends. That is, for a functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to \textbf{sSet}$ from some category to the category of simplicial sets, the **homotopy limit** of $F$ is defined to be
$$
\operatorname{holim}F = \int_{c\in\mathcal{C}}\textbf{sSet}(N(c\uparrow\mathcal{C}), F(c)).
$$
More details about this definition can be found [here](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/hocolimits.pdf). By definition of ends, the data of a homotopy limit consists of the object $\operatorname{holim}F$ together with natural maps
$$
p_c:\operatorname{holim} F \to \textbf{sSet}(N(c\uparrow\mathcal{C}), F(c))
$$
for each $c \in \mathcal{C}$. Formally, we say that $(\operatorname{holim}F, \{p_c\}_c)$ is a homotopy limit. I would like to prove the following claim.

**Claim:**  Suppose that, for each $c \in \mathcal{C}$, we have a map $p_c':\operatorname{holim}F \to \textbf{sSet}(N(c\uparrow \mathcal{C}), F(c))$ such that $p_c$ is homotopic to $p_c'$. Then $(\operatorname{holim} F, \{p_c'\}_c)$ is also a homotopy limit.

The point here is that I would like to replace the natural maps with homotopic maps, while preserving the property of being a homotopy limit. I think this should be possible, because the whole point of homotopy limits is that they work "modulo homotopy", in the sense that the construction cannot tell the difference between homotopic things. However, I am struggling to prove the claim from my actual definition involving ends. Could anybody help me to understand why this result is true? Ideally I would like a reference where the theorem is actually stated, but an explanation would also be very helpful.

Comment: I don't think your claim is true. For one thing, the universal property you are talking about is _strict_, because you are taking an end in the sense of 1-categories here.

Comment: @ZhenLin seems like a very reasonable objection haha. I guess my thinking was that changing the maps maybe gives you a different, but isomorphic wedge (where wedge is to end as cone is to limit - I'm not sure how widespread the terminology is).